# windows powershell display the current variable in the pipeline during a for each loop

Tags: powershell

Im deleting profiles using the get-wmi commandlet.  As the code goes through each delete command in the loop I would like to display which profile is being deleted.  I tried this:

```
$total = 0
$count = 1
foreach ($localpath in $dispaths)
{$total = $total + 1}
Foreach ($localpath in $dispaths) 
{cls
write-host "Deleting Profile: $_.localpath ($count of $total)"
$count = $count + 1
get-wmiobject -class win32_userprofile -computername $cname | where 
{$_.localpath -eq $localpath.localpath} | foreach {$_.Delete()}
}
```

but while the count works right, the display line shows literally:

Deleting Profile: ./localpath (1 of 135)

instead of displaying whatever the current string inside of the localpath variable is.  I tried removing the . from $._localpath but that just displayed something like this:

Deleting Profile: (1 of 135)

it doesnt display anything where the variable string should be.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is a `ForEach` loop not a `ForEach-Object`. So you need to use the variable defined in the `ForEach` Statement.

Your `Foreach`:

```
Foreach ($localpath in $dispaths)
```

So you'll need to properties on the variable `$localpath` not `$_`

```
write-host "Deleting Profile: $_.localpath ($count of $total)"
```

would become:

```
write-host "Deleting Profile: $($Localpath.localpath) ($count of $total)"
```

Note that this is different from your final line, as your are using `foreach` as the alias for `ForEach-Object`. So your line could more precisely written as:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $cname | 
    Where-Object {$_.localpath -eq $localpath.localpath} |
    ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}
```

So since this is line uses `ForEach-Object` and the pipeline you use `$_` for the values pass down the pipeline. But also uses `$localpath` from the parent `ForEach` loop.

Comment: Thanks again BenH for taking the time to show me how this goes.  I've never really learned powershell scripting from scratch.  I just need it to solve specific problems so a lot of the logical constructs and syntax behind it are missing from my experiece.

when I run the script with your changes I get more than just the localpath.  it shows the entire row for each run instead of just the local path cell for each.  It looks like this:

Deleting Profile: @{samaccountanme=rbobo; enabled=FALSE; Localpath=C:\Users\rbobo}.localpath (19 of 135)

any idea why?

Comment: @soltkr Answer updated to address the issue. It's because inside quotes when you are expanding variables, it just expands the variable with `.property` appended as a string. So put the `$variable.property` inside a subexpression `$()` and it'll evaluate the property.

Comment: you are absolutely correct.  new code worked perfectly!